# backup SharePoint O365

Tags: backup, restore, online

I want to backup a O365 site through PowerShell, but I couldn't find the command for it anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any direct option to backup sharepoint site in office 365.

For backup, you have to raise ticket to MSFT as they keep the backup for 14 days, but you can't restore on your own.

For more details refer to these links on other options...

https://threewill.com/the-4-options-you-need-to-know-about-sharepoint-online-backup-and-restore/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/akieft/2012/01/09/restore-options-in-sharepoint-online/